# Lengthy tasks using CQRS vs Service class in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, cqrs

I am working on a project in .NET Core to upload Excel files into MS SQL database. Will CQRS be a good way to implement this or traditional service class is better? As there are multiple rows in an excel, can I do field validation using Fluent API?

Answer (score 1):

CQRS seems like an overkill for doing a excel file importer. CQRS is perfect when you have a complex domain with a lot of focus on behavior and collaboration.

Yes, using https://fluentvalidation.net/ could be a good approach for implementing input validation in your project.